# controlling iframed ( embedded ) youtubeplayer thru custom play-pause buttons

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I searched the youtube API's and web but could not run into an tutorial that demonstrates the following:

Assume we got an embed like this:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src=""
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And we got a button like this:
`<button onclick="playVideo()">Play Video</button>`

And the playVideo function, does its own business logic and then say come up with a SRC url like this:

srcURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1';

At this point, to start the video, I currently do this ( and it works )

document.getElementById("ytplayer").src = srcURL;

My approach does works but limited. 
It does start the video but how do you stop it, pause it?

The tutorials I run into all got a starting point like this:

`... player = new YT.Player('player', { ...`

But that does not apply here. Is there a way to tell the browser, hey your ytplayer is in the iframe itself, then all the startVideo, stopVideo methods of the YT would work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), play, stop, pause only works when there's an instance of YT.Player.